# Executing an keypress event while playing a sound in python(tkinter)

Tags: python, audio, tkinter

I'm new to programming and I have very little knowledge of python. I'm a trying to make a program that will test auditory and visual reaction time for an experiment in biology.
For the auditory part, I'm starting the timer when the sound starts playing, the subject then has to press a key as soon as he hears it. My problem is that while the sound is still playing I can't execute anything else and thus can't record the time when the key is pressed. 
Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to do:

```
from Tkinter import *
import time
import winsound

def chooseTest(event):
    global start
    if event.keysym == 'BackSpace':
       root.after(2000,playSound)
    elif event.keysym == 'Return':
       new_time = time.clock()
       elapsed = new_time - start
       print elapsed
    else:
       pass

def playSound():
    global start
    start = time.clock()
    winsound.PlaySound('SystemAsterisk', winsound.SND_ALIAS)

root=Tk()
root.overrideredirect(True)
root.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(root.winfo_screenwidth(),root.winfo_screenheight()))           
root.bind('<Key>',chooseTest)
root.mainloop()
```

Whatever that I put under the  *elif event.keysym == 'Return':* is only executed after that the sound is finished.
Is there some way(hopefully not very complicated) to overcome this?
The only solution that I can come up with is to take a very short sound(millisecond?) and loop it until the key is pressed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to start the sound on a separate [thread](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread).

something like:

```
import threading

#...

def playSound():
    global start
    start = time.clock()

    def func(): 
        winsound.PlaySound('SystemAsterisk', winsound.SND_ALIAS)

    threading.Thread(target=func).start()
```

As a side note, having global values hanging around like this isn't the best solution.  You should read up on classes as they are a very nice way to have state shared between various function calls.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, it works. Can you comment on how accurate is it? I have read about time.time and time.clock and the time.clock seems to be more appropriate for my case (for windows). I'm not sure however how reliable my results are. I'm doing the same thing for the visual test only changing the background instead. Is there a delay between when the command to play a sound is received and the actual sound is played? and is it significantly different than the delay when changing the background? Thanks

Comment: I tried to use timeit to verify it. Is including only the  winsound.PlaySound... statement enough? I ran it several times but I see that the duration of the sound itself is included in my time. Should I just find out how long is that sound and subtract it? And what about the garbage collection? I'm not sure if I should enable it or not.

Comment: @user1830663: I think it will be very hard, maybe even impossible, to measure the delay especially within Python itself since it involves components outside of it doing things. Your best bet would be to obtain some empirical measurements.